# What should happen to the Pico tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

After a recent suggestion of mine to create a Raspberry Pi Pico tag (only to find out that one already exists), I wondered what should happen to the [pico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pico) tag.

This tag is currently used by three topics:

- The SI prefix (1 question)
- A brand of VR headset (1 question)
- The Raspberry Pi Pico (6 questions)

There are probably other purposes that people will use this tag for, as it has no description detailing its intended purpose.

In my opinion, this tag either needs a description or deletion. The questions related to the Pi Pico belong in [raspberry-pi-pico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-pico), with a statement added to the description to warn users against putting their Pi Pico questions in here.

There is also a text editor called [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)). Although people have asked questions about it, none of them were tagged with [pico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pico). The [nano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nano) tag hints that this might have been the intended purpose of the [pico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pico) tag:

> GNU nano is an open source, curses-based text editor for Unix systems. It is a clone of [pico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pico), the proprietary Pine e-mail client editor.

Comment: Or, perhaps, they are more on topic on [raspberrypi.se]?

Comment: Is the SI prefix really that valuable? I'm not sure we really need a tag for it. Perhaps it's best if that one question about that has the tag removed.

Comment: And the pico text editor! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)

Comment: By the way, there is also a command line editor for Unix called "pico". It's some sort of family with another editor called "nano" but I'm not sure of the relationship.

Comment: @Larnu Hardware-related questions could belong on Electronics. Raspberry Pi are [having a discussion about it](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/should-this-site-allow-pi-pico-or-rp2040-questions). However, questions related to programming of the Pi Pico are perfectly on-topic here, just as Arduino-related programming questions are.

Comment: I retagged all the raspery pi questions to [tag:raspberry-pi-pico]. There are now just two questions left. I'm not an expert in the other two, but I guess [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012026/the-nano-second-and-pico-seconds-metric-on-linux-kernel) should be closed as unclear. [The one about the vr headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67727707/parallel-use-pico-and-oculus), I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: @BDL Why you retag all question? The subject is still being discussed, and perhaps a better suggestion will emerge in the end?

Comment: It looks like there are no tags for other SI prefixes, other than ones which have something code-related named after them. This leaves us with just the VR headset and the text editor. Perhaps "pico" should be the text editor (it is very old for a computer thing - 1989, and the description of "nano" makes reference to this meaning) and we can create "pico-interactive" for the VR headset (their website is pico-interactive.com).

Comment: @Shree: What do you mean? The questions I retagged were wrongly tagged with pico although they were about [tag:raspberry-pi-pico]. What other solution do you expect for those questions? Usually, we don't even need a meta discussion to handle such small tags.

Comment: @BDL are you sure **we don't even need a meta discussion to handle such small tags** ?

Comment: I only started a meta discussion because I don't think I have enough reputation to take action myself.

Comment: I removed `pico` from the SI unit question and closed the VR headset one. The latter should go away automatically after some days, and the tag itself another day after that.

Comment: Or maybe they are talking about an anime called Boku no Pico. But I really, really hope that's not true.

Comment: @Shree not sure about tag discussion in general, but at least [it's true for tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/2821954): "*If you have authoritativea knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are **dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself** or with a little ad hoc help.*"

Comment: You've missed [Pico (the programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(programming_language)) for the possible overloads of the word `pico`.  Since that presumably means there are no questions about the programming language, maybe it doesn't matter yet — and a tag [tag:pico-language] would likely be appropriate.

Comment: Another topic: [Pico Rivera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_Rivera,_California#History_and_culture), a city in Los Angeles County that formed from the merging of Pico and Rivera (obviously a merger of the tags [pico] and [rivera]).

Comment: @iBug It looks like this tag might need manual deletion, as people keep creating Raspberry Pi Pico questions with this tag, so it will not auto-delete due to inactivity. I have added [burninate-request].

Comment: Re *"a text editor called Pico, which no one has asked any questions about"*: Not true. Some examples: *[How to turn off line wrap in the Pico editor when performing 'crontab -e'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970046/)* and *[Creating a file using Pico under a different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526685/creating-a-file-using-pico-under-a-different-directory)*. They are not tagged with Pico and probably should be.